# height style property doesn't work in div elements

Tags: css, html

I'm setting a height of 20px on a `<div>`, though when it renders in the browser, its only 14px high.

Any ideas?

```
<div style="display:inline; height:20px width: 70px">My Text Here</div>
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You cannot set `height` and `width` for elements with `display:inline;`.  Use `display:inline-block;` instead.

From [the CSS2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced):

> **10.6.1 Inline, non-replaced elements**
>
> The `height` property does not apply. The height of the content area should be based on the font, but this specification does not specify how. A UA may, e.g., use the em-box or the maximum ascender and descender of the font. (The latter would ensure that glyphs with parts above or below the em-box still fall within the content area, but leads to differently sized boxes for different fonts; the former would ensure authors can control background styling relative to the 'line-height', but leads to glyphs painting outside their content area.)

EDIT —  You're also missing a `;` terminator for the `height` property:

```
<div style="display:inline; height:20px width: 70px">My Text Here</div>
<!--                                  ^^ here                       -->
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/FpqtJ/**

Comment: @Jonathan: you're also missing a semi-colon after the height property.

Comment: Also for display flex and inline-flex causes some height mismatching depending of the size of its content

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me:

```
min-height: 14px;
height: 14px;
```

Comment: any idea why this is necessary sometimes? In my case I was trying to position a hidden div behind a fixed header and it wouldn't render with any height unless I did this.

Comment: This worked for me. I suppose this is necessary thanks to having the div in-question sharing a wrapper with other divs that are setup with percentage instead of a fixed width or height.

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure you add "**;**" to each style. Your excluding them from width and height and while it might not be causing your specific problem, it's important to close it.

```
<div style="height:20px; width: 70px;">My Text Here</div>
```

Comment: Closing the last css rule with a ; is not required, makes no functional difference and adds unnecessary markup

Answer (score 1):

You're loosing your height attribute because you're changing the **block** element to **inline** (it's now going to act like a `<p>`). You're probably picking up that 14px height because of the text height inside your in-line div.

Inline-block may work for your needs, but you may have to implement a work around or two for cross-browser support.

IE supports inline-block, but only for elements that are **natively inline**.

Answer (score 1):

Set positioning to absolute. That will solve the problem immediately, but might cause some problems in layout later. You can always figure out a way around them ;)

Example:

```
position:absolute;
```

Comment: This is not a good solution to OP's issue, since his problem has almost nothing to do with the `position` property. This will cause unnecessary layout problems, not ones that should be solved later.

Answer (score 1):

Position absolute fixes it for me. I suggest also adding a semi-colon if you haven't already.

```
.container {
    width: 22.5%;
    size: 22.5% 22.5%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: floralwhite;
    display:inline-block;
    min-height: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to set the `height` property of an `inline` element, which is not possible. You can try to make it a `block` element, or perhaps you meant to alter the `line-height` property?

Answer (score 0):

I'm told that it's bad practice to overuse it, but you can always add `!important` after your code to prioritize the css properties value.

```
.p{height:400px!important;}
```

Answer (score -1):

use the min-height property. min-height:20px;