# HTML: DIV inside a TABLE

Tags: html, css, html-table

Can I set the `height` of a `div` inside a `table` to `100%`? Failing that, can I use a `span` instead?

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4967633/563247) answer but it doesn't mention anything about `100%`.

[image]

[I need to use divs because they have dynamic content loading into them]

**EDIT**

In the images below you'll see that display is `table-cell`, I've set it to `block` and `inline-block` with the same result

[image]
[image]

Comment: you can load dynamic content into any element - just give it an identifier or smth

Comment: using `dojo`s `dojox.layout.ContentPane` :(

Comment: then do `div { display: table-cell; height: 100% }`

Comment: I've tried `table-cell` to no avail

Comment: Try setting `position: relative;` on the container (`<td>`?), then setting `height: 100%;` on the div. Often when I'm having trouble with sizing, setting the position property clears things up. This property does have certain important side effects (such as changing the z-order), so it may cause problems for a complex layout (nothing that can't be overcome, though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can as long as the element is block or inline-block as it states in the answer you posted.  Div's are block level by default and spans are inline, so need css display:inline-block or display:block.

Comment: Is that really the only way? I have been messing around with `block` and `inline-block` for the last hour and they mess up my layout :(

Comment: I think you need to show more of your code so we can see what is happening and what you want to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Like [this?](http://jsfiddle.net/QBaQN/) If you uncomment the // from before the height, it fills the td it is inside, is that what you are asking?

Comment: I think my code is more complex then I'm letting on that's why I'm getting these problems

Comment: Need to give us more information to help you then, do you have a link we can use?