# Span element bottom border overlap over paragraph element top border

Tags: html, css, border

The below code

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  border: 5px solid green;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}

span {
  border: 5px solid red;
}

p {
  border: 5px solid brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="span1">This is a span 1 </span>
  <p class="para1">This is a para 1</p>
</div>
```

[executed image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C97N.png)

“the above code creates the span bottom border overlap over the brown paragraph top border” why is it so, why not the paragraph top border is over the span bottom border.

i have read that inline elements bottom and top border properties are ignored, but i could not understand the above scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Inline elements don't have a proper `heigth` property (see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967613/height-style-property-doesnt-work-in-div-elements)).

Since the `span` doesn't have any `height`, the `p` will be displayed just below the `span` (and not below it's border), and the borders of your `span` and `p` will overlap.

The block elements are probably processed before the inline elements, that may be why the `span` (inline element) border is over the `p` (block element). But this may change on differents browsers. (But this is just a theory, don't take too much credit for it)

**Anyway**, if you want the top-border of your `p` tag to be displayed below the bottom-border of the `span` tag, one of the solutions is to use `display : inline-block;` :

```
span {
    border: 5px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, paragraph starting just below the span content is fine, as it ignores the span height. i know that changing the display value to inline-block will then make the browser to honor the border also, but the default behaviour of span overlaping the paragraph border is what i am unable to understand, i mean if span is first and paragrapph comes after it then the pargraph should have the precedence and should have overlapped the span bottom border, because for browser it anyway doesnot exists.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified painting order algorithm (which runs on preorder depth-first search tree traversal mechanism) for non-positioned in-flow descendant elements, considering none of the elements are creating a stacking context:

```
    ----------------- First Iteration of Tree Traversal ------------------
    
    1. If the element is a non-positioned block-level descendant:
      1. background color of element
      2. border of element
    2. If the element is a non-positioned inline descendant:
      1. do nothing and skip the element
    
    ----------------- Second Iteration of Tree Traversal -----------------
    
    1. If the element is a non-positioned block-level descendant:
      1. print its text content 
    2. If the element is a non-positioned inline descendant:
      1. background color of element
      2. border of element
      3. text content of element
```

Note 1: This above algorithm follows the step 4 and step 7 of the painting order algorithm defined in CSS 2.1 [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html).

For following code,

```css
span {
  border: 20px solid fuchsia;
  background-color: green;
}

div.first-div, div.second-div {
  border: 10px solid black;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-div">First Block Div</div>
  <span>Inline Span</span>
  <div class="second-div">Second Block Div</div>
</div>
```

Note 2: Here, all the elements in our example, like parent div, child divs, and span, do not create any stacking context. But, they reside inside the default stacking context formed by an html element.

Note 3: Here, consider the parent (root) block-level div element as a descendant (child) element of an html element.

[Tree Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHjw4.png)

Now according to preorder depth-first search algo., root element is visited first in first iteration, so background color of the root element (in our case, container div is the root element) is painted first.

Now continuing the first iteration from left to right OR top to bottom in our HTML document, on left side OR top side, first div is visited first and background color of the the first div is painted first and then border of the first div is painted. now the traversal finds second div after visiting span, now here in this first iteration, text content of root element + text content of both divs + span element are skipped because this first iteration of preorder depth first traversal is only for painting root element's background color and background color + border of the block level descendant elements in tree order. so second div is visited and background color of the the second div is painted and then border of the second div is painted.

Now first iteration ends and starts second iteration. now root element's css style is already painted and it has no text content, so skip root element and now again first div is visited after root element and the first div's text content is the only remaining part so the text content of first div is printed.

Now the traversal in the second iteration continues and visits the span element (going from left to right OR top to bottom in our HTML document) and thus background color of span element is painted first and then border of the span element is painted and at last the text content of the span element is printed.

Now finally, the traversal in second iteration visits the last div (second div) element (going from left to right) and as we know the background color and border of second div are already painted, so this time text content of the second div is printed.

Now second iteration ends and no more iterations because our elements are fully painted...

So, final painting order in brief:

1. background color of container div
2. first div background color + border
3. second div background color + border
4. first div's text content
5. span background color + border
6. span's text content
7. second div's text content

In your case which has code:

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="span1">This is a span 1 </span>
    <p class="para1">This is a para 1</p>
</div>
```

The painting order would be:

1. background color of the container div
2. background color and border for p element
3. background color and border for span element
4. text content for span element
5. text content for p element.

That is why you see the span's border is overlapping the p element's border even if p element comes after span in tree order.

```css
span.span1 {
  border: 30px solid fuchsia;
  background-color: green;
}

p.para1 {
  border: 10px solid black;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="span1">This is a span 1</span>
  <p class="para1">This is a para 1</p>
</div>
```

Note 4: Having an inline-level parent element and block-level descendent (child) elements is not a recommended practice according to the HTML specs. but if you are curious to know the painting order for inline-level root (parent) element having block and inline-level descendant (child) elements then have a look at the following tree diagram which has a painting order mentioned via numbers:

[Tree Diagram having inline root (parent) element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/368bH.png)

for code,

```
<div class="first-div">First Block Div</div>
<div class="second-div">Second Block Div</div>
<span>Inline Span</span>
```

The painting order will be:

1. first div background color + border
2. second div background color + border
3. first div text content
4. second div text content
5. span background color + border
6. span text content

for code,

```
<span>Inline Span</span>
<div class="first-div">First Block Div</div>
<div class="second-div">Second Block Div</div>
```

The painting order will be:

1. first div background color + border
2. second div background color + border
3. span background color + border
4. span text content
5. first div text content
6. second div text content

Answer (score 0):

It is because their margin is set to 0, so their borders are in the same place

Answer (score 0):

Among padding, border and margin, the only thing inline elements ignore is the the top and bottom margin, so they would overlap with the elements placed top and bottom of them.
They even take left and right margins.

You would expect the same overlap while increasing padding of inline element.